# How to show app as tile

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, tile, windows-8.1

I was asked to create a metro style app (I just grabbed VS2013) for windows 8.1 enterprise..

The app needs to show how to contact our help desk, give the IP Addresses and name of the machine and has to be shown as a tile.

I created a blank store app, added a basic page and have it working in the basic page.

How do I get the store app to show in the tile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on Microsoft Developer Network:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj991805.aspx